# NetBeans Java GUI builder

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a Java application that I can choose the *design* option next to *source* and use the GUI builder but some are without that option *design* and I cannot use GUI builder on them. Is there a way to use GUI builder if that option is not present there?

Comment: If they don't have that option then it's likely they are not Swing top classes (frames or dialogs) and then they can't be "designed".

Comment: What does a form generator do? Will that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only switch between **Source** and **Design** if you created that file as a **Swing GUI Form** through the *New File* window of NetBeans. This is the window I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only choose when you select a JForm rather than a Java Class